# Cant send ether from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, contract-design, cpp-ethereum

I have 2 contract

```
contract A{


uint bidValue;

   address bidder;

   function bid() public payable{

   bidValue = msg.value;    

   bidder = tx.origin;

   }

}
```

And contract B :

```
import A.sol;

contract B{    

  function aBid() public payable{


    A a = A(address);    

    a.bid.value(msg.sender);

  }

}
```

Some how when i call aBid() from contract B and send ether along with it contract A still get msg.value = 0 and tx.origin = address(0).
After checking balance of contract A and B seem like eth value stuck in contract B.

Edit : the problem is the "()" after a.bid.value(msg.sender) but when i add it to my contract the gas fee needed to call that function increase to near infinity. For now all i can do is set gasPrice to 1 so it work like normal :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I flattened it into a single file in Remix for simplicity. As separate files, B.sol will need import "./A.sol"; as in your original code.

I fiddled around with it until it worked. There is a fair bit to sort out on a line-by-line basis. This works as expected:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract A {

   uint public bidValue;
   address public bidder;

   function bid() public payable {
     bidValue = msg.value;    
     bidder = msg.sender;
   }
}

contract B {    

  function aBid(address aAddress) public payable{
    A a = A(aAddress);    
    a.bid.value(msg.value)();
  }
}
```

1. Deploy A
2. Copy A's address the clipboard
3. Deploy B, passing A's address into the constructor
4. Send some funds to B.aBid()
5. Inspect A's bidValue() and bidder() functions.

You can improve B a little bit by passing in A's address just one time on deployment instead of every single time.

```
contract B {    

  A a; // An "A" known as "a" with the address stored in the contract

  constructor(address aAddress) public {
      a = A(aAddress);
  }

  function aBid() public payable{
    a.bid.value(msg.value)();
  }
}
```

Following SMarx's suggestion, B can be more concise:

```
contract B {    

  A a;

  constructor(A _a) public {
      a = _a;
  }

  function aBid() public payable{
    a.bid.value(msg.value)();
  }
}
```

There is also the `interface` concept which will be worth looking into as an optimization. I only mention that for completeness.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My problem seem to be that "()" after .value(msg.value) but when i apply it to my code the gas price jump though the roof. Now im really confused.

Comment: `constructor(A _a) public { a = _a; }` would be better. No need to bypass type checking.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
a.bid.value(msg.sender);
```

should be:

```
a.bid.value(msg.value)();
```

You were passing `msg.sender` instead of `msg.value`, and you were missing the parentheses to actually call the function.